# cannot load webpage on google cloud platform using IP address

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I cannot load a webpage using Google Cloud Platform compute engine, Linux server.

I am using the IP address. I checked the boxes to allow HTTP and HTTPS traffic.
I can ping the IP address and receive 4 replies.

I installed php 7.3 and apache2.
I started the apache server, and verified that the apache server is running. Then I did not change any configurations.
The doc root is still set to /var/www/html.  the default webpage still exists.  I just deployed this server, and it have never worked.

A previous similar question answer suggest enabling firewall rules.  I checked firewall rules for this server.

HTTP and HTTPS ingress is allowed.
The firewall rules are set as follows:

```
default-allow-http
Ingress
http-server
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:80
Allow
1000
default
Off
—
default-allow-https
Ingress
https-server
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:443
Allow
1000
default
```

Why, please?

Comment: If you ssh into the instance and curl localhost:80 or curl localhost:443, do you receive the content of the page?

Comment: curl localhost:80 produces the HTML for what appears to be the default apache webpage.  This is the expected result.  curl localhost:443 produces a failed to load error

Comment: If on `localhost:80` you see the default apache and if ingress 80 firewall rule is applied to your instance, then you should see the same nginx default page when you curl the `external-instance-IP:80`

Comment: curl external-instance-IP:80 produces Could not resolve host: external-instance-IP

Comment: curl 35.223.119.208 produces the default apache webpage.  this is the expected result

Comment: it just started working.  I did not make any changes, so I am not sure what happened.  thanks for your help

Comment: great! glad I could help.

Comment: the reason it it was not working is that the link to load the site from the GCP console defaults to https:// .  The reason it started working is that I changed https:// to http://

Answer (score 1):

- Check if the apache service is running
- ssh into the GCE instance and check if you can get the page content locally

```
curl localhost:80
curl localhost:443
```

- Make sure that the ingrees rule that allows traffic on port 80 and 443 is applied to the instance